# Get a double from boost::chrono::steady_clock::now()

Tags: c++, boost

How would I get a double value from boost::chrono::steady_clock::now()?
I don't believe there is a .count() parameter for this.

Why do I need this? I have a method that cannot parse the boost return.

Comment: A `double` indicating what?

Comment: now() returns time since boot I believe. I want that as a double.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- [`boost::chrono::steady_clock::now()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/chrono/reference.html#chrono.reference.cpp0x.system_clocks_hpp.steady_clock) returns a `boost::chrono::time_point`.
- [`boost::chrono::time_point`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/chrono/reference.html#chrono.reference.cpp0x.time_point_hpp.time_point) has a `time_since_epoch` method which returns a `boost::chrono::duration`.
- [`boost::chrono::duration`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/chrono/reference.html#chrono.reference.cpp0x.duration_hpp.duration) has a `count` method  that gives you a scalar.

When we put it all together, it boils down to:

```
auto now = boost::chrono::steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch();
auto timeSinceEpoch = boost::chrono::duration_cast<boost::chrono::milliseconds>(now).count();
```

Granted that's not a `double` but close enough: you can change the `duration_cast` to get whatever precision you need and/or divide the `timeSinceEpoch` to your liking so that your `double` fits your requirements. For example:

```
// Days since epoch, with millisecond (see duration_cast above) precision
double daysSinceEpoch = double(timeSinceEpoch) / (24. * 3600. * 1000.);
```

Answer (score 9):

you can specify `double` inside `duration`:

```
auto some_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
double duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double>>(some_time).count();
```

Comment: The high_resolution_clock isn't necessarily a steady_clock, so it might not satisfy the original question of converting a steady_clock to a double.